# Pc gaming assassins creed

Tags: windows-10

I’ve recently bought Assassins Creed origins and it’s quite laggy when walking around with the keyboard and mouse the response time is poor but the graphics are great.

Would getting a gamepad, solve the problem, I describe?

Specifications:

- Processor: Intel Core  i3-1700U CPU @ 2.40GHz
- Ram: 12.0
- System type: 64 bit
- GPU: Intel hd graphics 620
- API: directX 11

Comment: Hardware recommendations are out of scope here at Superuser.  Since you are looking for hardware recommendations, even though I answered your question, I am going to vote to close this question.  If you are looking to replace your CPU, that would involve getting a new motherboard, since none of the compatible CPUs that work with your motherboard get even close to meeting the minimum specifications of [Assassin's Creed® Origins](https://store.steampowered.com/app/582160/Assassins_Creed_Origins/) that is a futile upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

> it’s quite laggy when walking around with the keyboard and mouse the response time is poor

The performance problems you describe is due to your system specifications.  Your system does not meet the requirements for the game.

[image]

> Would getting a gamepad, solve the problem, I describe?

It absolutely would not solve your performance problems.

Source: [Assassin's Creed® Origins](https://store.steampowered.com/app/582160/Assassins_Creed_Origins/)

Comment: What graphics card should I buy to to fix the lagging?

Comment: https://www.bestbuy.com/site/pny-nvidia-geforce-gt-710-verto-2gb-ddr3-pci-express-2-0-graphics-card-black/5092306.p?skuId=5092306&cmp=RMX&extStoreId=1064&ref=212&loc=1&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIgeCV4t-P3QIVnlcNCh0sZQIFEAQYAiABEgKncvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds Would this be a good card?

Comment: @Greyson That card is still well below the minimum specs of the game. Should you use it, you may have to turn down the graphical quality to improve performance.

Comment: @Greyson - Hardware recommendations are out of scope here at Superuser.  You don't need us to determine what hardware must be upgraded to run [Assassin's Creed® Origins](https://store.steampowered.com/app/582160/Assassins_Creed_Origins/),